# Reorganize/Restructure Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to reorganize my pandas dataframe.

Currently my dataframe looks like this:

| Name | C | Nr | Value | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 1 | 1.1 | p |
| 1 | B | 2 | 1.3 | p |
| 1 | G | 1 | 2.4 | p |
| 1 | G | 2 | 2.5 | p |
| 2 | B | 1 | 4.4 | n |
| 2 | B | 2 | 8.0 | n |
| 2 | G | 1 | 8.1 | n |
| 2 | G | 2 | 7.0 | n |
| 3 | B | 1 | 9.2 | p |
| 3 | G | 1 | 6.5 | p |

and i want my dataframe to look like this

| ID | B1 | B2 | G1 | G2 | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 1.3 | 2.4 | 2.5 | p |
| 2 | 4.4 | 8.0 | 8.1 | 7.0 | n |
| 3 | 9.2 | N/A | 6.5 | N/A | p |

So far i was not able to find a combination of groupby stack unstack to solve this problem.

Do you have any ideas?

The real dataframe is much bigger with ~10000 rows and the desired dataframe would have 800 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) For MultiIndex in index and columns DataFrame and then `map` columns for flatten values:

```
df = df.pivot(index=['Name','R'], columns=['C','Nr'], values='Value')
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   Name  R   B1   B2   G1   G2
0     1  p  1.1  1.3  2.4  2.5
1     2  n  4.4  8.0  8.1  7.0
2     3  p  9.2  NaN  6.5  NaN
```

If `R` column should be last:

```
df['R'] = df.pop('R')
print (df)

   Name   B1   B2   G1   G2  R
0     1  1.1  1.3  2.4  2.5  p
1     2  4.4  8.0  8.1  7.0  n
2     3  9.2  NaN  6.5  NaN  p
```